# Need For Loop Process with Python and Selenium using JSON Information Loaded or Other Method

Tags: python, json, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I need help with making a for loop for a selenium process using python. 
The goal here is to load up into a page on a specific website after authentication:

1. Authenticate to Website
2. Load a Namekey
3. Send_keys Namekey and Hit Enter
4. Click a button to remove user with Namekey from all security groups
5. Click okay to confirm

Steps 2-5 have to be done for 3000 users.
This is the code of block that actually does the process.

```py
# Send Keys to Lookup 
# XPATH = //*[@id='brSecuredUsersLookupInput']
target_user = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='brSecuredUsersLookupInput']")))

# Start Forloop
target_user.send_keys(config['sec_group_removal']['name_key']);
target_user.send_keys(Keys.RETURN);

# Expand Button on Element Needing Sec Group Removal
# Class "bd_open"
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "bd_closed")))
element.click()

# Click on Remove All Groups By Link Text
# find_elements_by_link_text
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Remove All Groups")))
element.click()

# Click Ok by ID
# XPATH //*[@id='msgBtn1'] 
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='msgBtn1']")))
element.click()
# End For Loop
```

I have four questions related to this:

1. Can I make this into a for-loop and load the users via `JSON` or should I make a dictionary?
2. How can I go about making a for-loop to iterate over this process should I do a `for i in dictionary` statement, or a `while` statement?
3. I have to load the information from a separate file as I don't want the namekeys hard-coded into the script. Is `JSON` the best way to do this? I had an issue with my `JSON`file earlier where I tried to do multiple users nested within the `JSON` file but it wasn't working. Perhaps it's not best practice to create a dictionary off of nested `JSON`?
4. Is there another way to load information from a separate file other than something similar to this:

```py
# Load users.json File 
with open('users.json','r') as f:
          config = json.load(f)
```

Also here are the JSON files I have been using to help load this

The JSON File that works:

```
{
        "sec_group_removal": {
                "name_key": "<INSERT_NAMEKEY>"
        }
}
```

this obviously correlates to `(config['sec_group_removal']['name_key'])` but when I used a file like this:

```
{
                "sec_group_removal": {
                        "target_users": {
                                "user_1": {
                                        "first_name": "<INSERT_FIRST_NAME>",
                                        "last_name": "<INSERT_LAST_NAME>",
                                        "user_name": "<firstname.lastname>",
                                        "name_key": "<INSERT_NAMEKEY>"
                                        },
                                "user_2": {
                                        "first_name": "<INSERT_FIRST_NAME>",
                                        "last_name": "<INSERT_LAST_NAME>",
                                        "user_name": "<firstname.lastname>",
                                        "name_key": "<INSERT_NAMEKEY>"
                                }
                        }
                }
}
```

I don't have to use a `JSON` file to load it, for example I have an excel file, text file, or csv file that contains the information as well needed to place in the namekey of the user. Any thoughts or directions here would be nice. Either way I don't think loading the `JSON`from a separate file is the way to go. But for curiosity sake this did not work:

```py
(config['sec_group_removal']['target_users']['user_1']['name_key'])
```

Furthermore, I realize that the `['user_1'] would have to be a variable defined from the`JSON` file itself.